# Using gdb's define to dispatch on type

Tags: gdb

In GDB I'd like to define a function that dispatches on type. Here is a simple example of something I have in mind:

```
define test
   if (ptype(1) == int)
     p 2
   end
end
```

The above gives me a message saying that: No symbol "ptype" in current context.
Can something like this be done without going to python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can something like this be done without going to python?

No.

Python scripting is *exactly* what you need here.